# How to rename files using Zsh shell and `sed` command on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, shell, sed, zsh

I have a folder on my desktop called "Images", inside that folder are 3 images...

```
File-A-B.gif
File-C-D.gif
File-E-F.gif
```

...I want to rename the files on the command line so the second hyphen/dash is removed. So the result would be files named like so...

```
File-AB.gif
File-CD.gif
File-EF.gif
```

...I'm using a combination of commands piped through to each other but not having much luck in getting them to work.

Initially I had `ls File-* | sed 's/\(File-[^-]\)-\(.+\)/mv & \1\2/' | sh`

The break-down of this command is...

- list out any files that begin `File-`
- pipe the results through to `sed`
- we'll use `sed` to capture different parts of the name
- looking at the first file we'll capture the `File-A` and the `B.gif`
- with `sed` we then replace the matched file name with a move command and effectively tell it to rename the original file to a file made up of the two pieces of data we've captured
- we then pipe that command through to `sh`

The initial error I was getting was a permissions error. I'm not sure why as I had 'read and write' access to the files.

To work around this I `chmod 777` each of the files.

This then resulted in a new error which was `cannot execute binary file`.

To work around that error I saw this post: http://blog.mpdaugherty.com/2010/05/27/difference-with-sed-in-place-editing-on-mac-os-x-vs-linux/ which suggests adding an extra pair of single quotes. The reason this works (apparently) is because `sed` will error because it doesn't know what file extension to use, but putting an empty String neutralises that error (on a side note: my understanding was that you also need to use the `-i` flag - which I'm not using - but doing that caused a different error so I scrapped that and just used the single quotes to avoid the binary file error I was getting).

So now I have `ls File-* | sed '' 's/\(File-[^-]\)-\(.+\)/mv & \1\2/' | sh`

But this errors with `No such file or directory`?

I tried to be explicit with the location of the file, so for example...

```
ls File-* | sed '' 's/\(File-[^-]\)-\(.+\)/mv ~\/Desktop\/Images\/& ~/Desktop\/Images\/\1\2/' | sh
```

...notice I've had to escape the forward slashes `~\/Desktop\/Images\/` but this still didn't work.

I also installed the GNU version of `sed` using Homebrew but it also errored in a similar way with `gsed: can't read s/\(Vim-[^-]\)-\(.+\)/mv & \1\2/: No such file or directory`

I'm a bit at a loss with how I can get this to work.

I don't want to have to resort to writing a bash/zsh script or a Ruby script.

Any help you can give me would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should work for you:

```
ls File-* | sed 's/\(.*\)-\(.*\)/mv & \1\2/' | sh
```

What you tried

```
ls File-* | sed '' 's/\(File-[^-]\)-\(.+\)/mv & \1\2/' | sh
```

was pretty close.  Saying:

```
ls File-* | sed '' 's/\(File-[^-]*\)-\(.*\)/mv & \1\2/' | sh
```

instead would have worked.

Comment: Thanks! It seems the first option you mentioned worked for me but it did produce an error in output (even though it correctly renamed the files)? 

The error was `preexec:4: command not found: ^A^B` do you have any idea what that means? Side note, your last example which you say was what I almost had, didn't work. 

But I can see why the first version works (I think), we're interpolating the other commands using combination of `echo` and `$()`. I'm not 100% sure what `$()` is normally used for though? 

Could you add extra explanation to your answer to help me (and others) understand better :)

Comment: `$()` is process substitution.  I guess since we're anyways piping to `sh` it's not required.  See edit above.

Comment: Just to be clear for others reading this: I made two mistakes in my original version. The biggest mistake was that I'd used `+` (which typical in regexp means "one or more") but that's not supported, so I needed `*` (which means "zero or more"). The other mistake which didn't actually effect anything but might cause someone else confusion is I missed an `*`. So `(File-[^-]\)` passed `File-A-B.gif` but would have failed `File-AB-C.gif` so it should have been `(File-[^-]*\)` instead (i.e. `[^-]*` means "match anything that isn't a `-` "zero or more times").

Comment: btw I was interested to see how it worked using `$()` but `ls File-* | sed 's/\(.*\)-\(.*\)/echo $(mv & \1\2)/'` generated an error for me so I guess the `echo $()` section doesn't work by itself?

Comment: @Integralist Can't say what's the possible issue since I'm not on a Mac, but it should have also worked.

Answer (score 12):

If you're using `zsh`, you don't need to use `sed`: there's a [zsh module called `zmv`](http://zshwiki.org/home/builtin/functions/zmv) that'll achieve this pretty simply:

```
$ ls -F -G
File-A-B.gif  File-C-D.gif  File-E-F.gif

$ zmv -n 'File-(*)-(*).gif' 'File-${1}${2}.gif'
mv -- File-A-B.gif File-AB.gif
mv -- File-C-D.gif File-CD.gif
mv -- File-E-F.gif File-EF.gif
```

**Note:** Omit `-n` to get it to actually run.

It works by matching things inside brackets. In this case: `File-(*)-(*).gif` will both match `File-A-B.gif` and also save `A` and `B` so we can refer to them later. Then, we move the file we've just matched to a new filename, omitting the hyphen between the two letters and inserting the letters using references: `File-${1}${2}.gif`.

It's quite a powerful little module, provided you can give it the two regexes: one to match files to rename, and the second to match the renamed-file name.

Comment: In case of `zsh: command not found: zmv` load it with `autoload -U zmv`. Details about this function `man zshcontrib`

Answer (score 0):

Another way this can be done is with mv, for example:

```
mv <current-filename> <new-filename>
```